# Oracle RTRIM of a listagg issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of values that, as part of a dynamic query, form tuples for an `in` clause.

To do this, I have used a listagg, adding `'),('1','` to each value, then using `rtrim` to remove the last value:

```
with r1 as
    (
    select 1 as id, 'XYZ1' as r_val
    from dual
    union all
    select 2, 'ABC1'
    from dual
    )
select rtrim(listagg(r1.r_val, 
                     '''),(''1'',''') within group (order by r1.r_val),
             '''),(''1'',''' )
from r1
```

Expected:

```
ABC1'),('1','XYZ1
```

However, for some reason, if the r_val ends with a `1`, the `1` is trimmed also:

```
ABC1'),('1','XYZ
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters for `RTRIM()` form a set, not a single string.  So each is treated individually (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions141.htm)).

I don't see why the `RTRIM()` is needed at all for this query.  `listagg()` only puts the separator string *between* values.

This should do what you want:

```
select listagg(r1.r_val, 
               '''),(''1'',''') within group (order by r1.r_val)
              )
```

Comment: Spectacular, thanks G. It's old code from someone else, I'm trying to clean up this bug, makes much more sense now